# How to generate a Litecoin Private key and correspondent Public Address in C#

Tags: blockchain, litecoin, cryptography, c#, .net

I found this C# tool to generate addresses for Bitcoin (compressed and uncompressed):

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoin_Address_Utility

https://github.com/casascius/Bitcoin-Address-Utility

It works perfectly for Bitcoin, but for Litecoin it seems not to work.

Any ideas how to use similar code to generate Litecoin Addresses?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's odd, since BAU's docs say that they ought to work with Litecoin. In the drop-down menu that selects the coin type, have you selected Litecoin?

Alternately, if you're willing to run an RPC node, you could use [BitcoinLib](https://github.com/GeorgeKimionis/BitcoinLib), and call `CoinService.GetNewAddress(String)`.

Generally, it's exactly the same as generating Bitcoin addresses, except that the version byte is 48 instead of 0.

Comment: I accepted your answer because of your Alternative suggestion of using CoinService.GetNewAddress(String). That sounds like a very good idea, since Bitcoinlib supports not just Bitcoin but other altcoins. Thanks a lot!

For the record - Selecting Litecoin in the Drop Down Menu DOESN'T WORK, it generates wrong addresses. it looks that Bitcoin_Address_Utility is just  working 100% for Bitcoin.

Answer (score -2):

Bitcoin and Litecoin have different inner workings, so many of their parts shouldn't be interchangeable.

A short answer to your question could be: do you know C++ ? In this case, you could take a look at the parts of the reference implementation of Litecoin where the addresses are generated, and adapt it to C#.

Another answer would be to find an alternative library, independent of Litecoin reference implementation. One such implementation seems to be [Litecoin-PHP-Library](https://github.com/MadCapsule/Litecoin-PHP-Library), that is a heavily commented PHP code, where you can find answers to your questions. Good luck.

Comment: `Bitcoin and Litecoin have different inner workings, so many of their parts shouldn't be interchangeable.` That's not really true. They're vastly similar.

Comment: Similar doesn't mean equal or interchangeable.